# JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable async processing and torn JSON stream behaviour

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, json-deserialization, system.text.json, iasyncenumerable

Having had to solve the problem of iterating through the YEILDed results from a C# IAsyncEnumerable controller method myself with Javascript, by writing my own iterator to handle JSON tears, I was extolling the virtues of the C# JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable method to the team as doing all the heavy lifting for us.

Then my tests show that: -

```
IAsyncEnumerable<SearchName?> resultNames = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<SearchName>(outStream, opts, cancellationSource.Token);
await foreach (SearchName name in resultNames){
    Console.WriteLine(Uri.UnescapeDataString(name.familyName));
}
```

Won't start iterating until the entire buffer (resultNames) has been retrieved from the server and reassembled into an array by DeserializeAsyncEnumerable :-(

Do I have to write my own iterator and cater for tears in JSON chunks just like I did in Javascript?

[Here at Github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/56055) is a similar question. Sadly, when I follow the [Bug Fix](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/56080)  it says: -

"Fixes regression introduced by #51702: the ContinueDeserialize method will return 'null' on partial reads so ***no elements will be yielded by the enumerator until the entire stream has been consumed***."

My question is how can I make JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable (or use another C# strategy) start returning the Enumerable content Asynchronously as soon as it is available as a partial result?

Comment: Where is the stream coming from? If it's coming off `HttpResponseMessage` you need to use `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`

Comment: The stream originates from a HttpClient: - Stream outStream = await client.GetStreamAsync(URL, cancellationToken);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, found the answer on the next [search link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63864)

TLDR; The [buffer size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.defaultbuffersize?view=net-7.0) controls the behaviour:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<SearchName?> resultNames = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<SearchName>(
    outStream, 
    new JsonSerializerOptions { 
        DefaultBufferSize = 100, //** Set this value
        AllowTrailingCommas = true }, 
    cancellationSource.Token);
```